# Changing .NET Minimum Log Level programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, logging, f#

Using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, let be the log initialization (F#):

```
let myLogger = 
    LoggerFactory
        .Create(fun builder -> 
            builder
                .AddSimpleConsole()
                .SetMinimumLevel(myLevel) 
                |> ignore)
        .CreateLogger()
```

How do we change that minimum level later, on demand?

I am looking to something as simple as:

```
myLogger.ChangeMinimumLevelTo(newLevel)
```

Comment: [You can't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#change-log-levels-in-a-running-app): `The Logging API doesn't include a scenario to change log levels while an app is running`. Specific providers may allow this. You're only using a Console provider right now but if you use Serilog you'll be able to [use dynamic level switches](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#dynamic-levels).

Comment: BTW the code you wrote looks like an attempt to emulate Serilog and the singleton Logger instance. In .NET Core the `ILogger` is specific to a category. An `ILogger<T>` is an `ILogger` whose category is the name of the type `T`. You should only share the LoggerFactory and use it to create loggers as needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little dirty, but it works ([Mono.Reflection](https://github.com/jbevain/mono.reflection/) used for GetBackingField)

```
let changeMinimumLevel (logger: ILogger) (level: LogLevel) = 
    let logger = logger :?> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger<obj>
    let _logger = 
        logger
            .GetType()
            .GetField("_logger", BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(logger)
    let loggersArray = 
        _logger
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty("MessageLoggers")
            .GetValue(_logger) :?> Array

    let loggers = seq { 
        let enu = loggersArray.GetEnumerator()
        while enu.MoveNext() do enu.Current 
    }

    loggers |> Seq.iteri (fun i info ->            
        let piMinLevel = info.GetType().GetProperty("MinLevel")
        let fiMinLevel = piMinLevel.GetBackingField()
        fiMinLevel.SetValue(info, Nullable(level))
        loggersArray.SetValue(info, i)
    )
```

Comment: "A little dirty" 

Comment: @BrianBerns yeah, I typoed lot with little :)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else needing this solution, but in **C#**, this is @Franco Tiveron's solution translated:

```
void changeMinimumLevel(ILogger logger, LogLevel level)
        {
            var _logger = logger
                    .GetType()
                    .GetField("_logger", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .GetValue(logger);
            var loggersArray =
                (Array)_logger
                    .GetType()
                    .GetProperty("MessageLoggers")
                    .GetValue(_logger);


            var enu = loggersArray.GetEnumerator();
            var i = 0;
            while (enu.MoveNext())
            {
                var x = enu.Current;
                var piMinLevel = x.GetType().GetProperty("MinLevel");
                var fiMinLevel = piMinLevel.GetBackingField();
                fiMinLevel.SetValue(x, level);
                loggersArray.SetValue(x, i);
                i++;
            }
        }
```